# Excel Form with check box selection that copy to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have been creating a spreadsheet where a user can fill out the vba form, select save and this then adds all the data to a table in a spreadsheet.

I would like to give the user the option to select multiple statements via checkboxes and the they get added to the table in a single cell. for example,

I have 6 checks boxes with "Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 etc." The user then selects Option 1 and Option 5 only. When they select save I would like the form to copy the date into the spreadsheet in the following format "Option 1; Option5"

Can anyone point me in the right direction to a tutorial? I'm struggling to find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic solution is to check each checkbox individually and then append some text to a string:

```
dim celltext as string

if UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True then
    celltext = celltext & "Foo;"
end if

if UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True then
    celltext = celltext & "Bar;"
end if

' And so on ... (for every checkbox)

' Eventually write the string the the target cell
Range("A1").value = celltext
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Does exactly what I wanted and so simple to add.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use linked cells for each checkbox.
2. Set them to a hidden worksheet.
3. List item

Concatenate them in your results.

*No VBA required.*

Select your checkbox, bring up the Format Control dialog, under the Control tab is an option for "Cell link". Pick where you want that control to go (e.g. first one in A1 in "My hidden sheet" - let's call it Outcomes - Outcomes!$A$1).

Put this formula in your results cell:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Outcomes!$A$1), "", Outcomes!$A$1&";")&IF(ISBLANK(Outcomes!$A$2), "", Outcomes!$A$2&";") & IF(ISBLANK(Outcomes!$A$3), "", Outcomes!$A$3&";") & IF(ISBLANK(Outcomes!$A$4), "", Outcomes!$A$4&";") & IF(ISBLANK(Outcomes!$A$5), "", Outcomes!$A$5&";")
```

`ISBLANK`checks if the cell is blank because you don't want to add an empty semicolon.

You'll end up with an extra ";" at the end.

What I would suggest is split it into a few helper fields.

1. Use A1-A5 for linking to the checkbox.
2. Use B1-B5 with the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "", A1&";"`
3. B6 is your concat - `=B1&B2&B3&B4&B5`
4. Now we can get rid of the last ";"
5. B7 = `RIGHT(B6, LEN(B6) - 1)`
6. Link your results field to Outcomes!B7